# Do I get my reputation refunded if a bad answer gets deleted?

Tags: support

If I vote a bad answer negatively, I lose rep as a voter. So if the answer gets deleted eventually, do I get my rep back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

If the answer gets deleted, all votes on it are null and void (both for answerer and voter)*, so you will get your rep back.

*There's [some caveats](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) about deleted answers with postive score, but I don't assume that's relevant in this instance.